# Does Halflife 2 run on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, games, support

Does the install disk version of halflife 2 support Ubuntu?  If not, is there any other version that supports Ubuntu?  If there is no Ubuntu version then could I run it through WINE?

Comment: How do we know what you have on your disk? There is HL2 in steam for linux.

Comment: I understand but isn't that a version that is played through an online server? And how much do I need to pay...again... for a game I already paid for at game stop and own outright?

Comment: I think you can add to steam a purchased CD version and you can play it using an online server. You better look at steam site.

Comment: If you had it installed via Steam on Windows, you just need to log into that account and it should show up, just click the install button and the download should start.  Any game that is released for Linux(or Mac for that matter) is automatically available for you to install on that platform if you already own it on your account.

Comment: and to answer your other comment, no you do not play hl2 on and online server.  It is installed in Steam, you can play it in offline mode or with no internet connection(after the install)

Answer (score 6):

Add your CD-key to your Steam account and you will get access to the game on all platforms for free.

TrailRider adds:

> You will just need to download the Linux version. This is assuming
>   that the OP has a Steam key with the disk (hard to tell the way the
>   question is phrased) If you use the same steam account on every system,
>   you just need to click the install button to start the download.

Comment: +1 you will just need to download the Linux version.  This is assuming that the OP has a Steam key with the disk(hard to tell the way the question is worded)  If he uses his Steam account that had it installed in Windows it should already be there in fact, and just need to click the install button to start the download. (feel free to add this to your answer if you wish)

Answer (score 1):

You can run halflife 2 using wine, not need Steam.

I just test it a few days before in 16.04. It works well.